# preg_match_all to check a special structure

Tags: php, preg-match

Hi i want to check with `preg_match_all` if a string consist of vowel and consonant.
The structure should be as `consonant|vowel|consonant|vowel`.

For example:

```
xaxa
xuxu
baba
nunu
```

Comment: What part are you struggling with? Did you read the manual on regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky because, while my first instinct was to match vowels and then not-vowels, It also matched everything else. Then there are rules in English with `y` sometimes being a vowel.

This should get you there.

```
$string = "xaxa xuxu baba nunu nnnn";
$vowels = 'aeiouy';
$consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz';
$pattern = "!([$consonants][$vowels][$consonants][$vowels])!i";
$found = preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $value){
    echo $value."<br />";
}
```

Strange thing about English is this will also match `yyyy`. If you wish not to treat `y` as a vowel, you can remove it from the group.

```
$vowels = 'aeiou';
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I don't must set up the consonants? I tried it but it don't find anything. But I can see it. Or how I can show only the entries that match?

Comment: My first answer matched stuff that was not letters also.

Comment: Ah ok now I get an answer like these:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => xaxa [1] => xuxu [2] => baba [3] => nunu ) [1] => Array ( [0] => xaxa [1] => xuxu [2] => baba [3] => nunu ) ) 

But I want to have xaxa, xuxu every in a new line.... And the negativ matches I don't want to see.

Answer (score 0):

This script check the alternating vowel/consonant for each word and returns them:

```
$subject = <<<LOD
abacagopa
titot
blux
apocop
pipo
laek
LOD;

$pattern = '~
# definitions
(?(DEFINE)(?<vowel>[aeiou]))
(?(DEFINE)(?<consonant>[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwyz]))

# pattern
\b\g<vowel>?+(?>\g<consonant>\g<vowel>)*+\g<consonant>?+\b

~ix';

echo preg_replace($pattern, '$0<br/>', $subject);
```